# Include Javascript / CSS min version on production and full on dev in ASP .NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to achieve a goal specified in the question topic in ASP .NET for instance with existing controls like ScriptManager or any other controls? I'm using ASP .NET Web Forms 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the bundler tool.  IF you aren't on the latest version of .NET, you can use the nuget package `bundler.net` to achieve the same.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification  Here's a reference guide to using the bundler.